# How to make Xcode 10 dark without changing the theme of the OS?

Tags: xcode, macos, user-interface, themes

I know, that in **macOS Mojave** and **Xcode 10** i can enable the dark Xcode theme by changing the whole OS's theme to dark in System Preferences.
But i used to use the bright OS theme and want to make dark only Xcode. Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode 10, open terminal and execute this command

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSWindowDarkChocolate -bool true
```